# CentOS-6.6 installed within VirtualBox-5.1.22 doesn't support screen resize

Tags: virtualbox, centos

VirtualBox-5.1.22-115126-Win.exe
CentOS-6.6-x86_64-minimal.ova

I followed the https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest and 
have successfully installed the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. Also, I have confirmed the installation as follows:

$ lsmod | grep vboxguest
vboxguest             219348  2 vboxsf

Question> Why the window size is still small and cannot resize to take the whole monitor?

[image: The under-size the window]

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solve this issue?